# Weird RecyclerView and ListView behavior

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

First of all sorry for my poor English.

I have a problem with the `RecyclerView`. I have a layout with `EditText`, submit button and a `RecyclerView`.

I can enter some text into `EditText`, then I click on submit and text is added to `RecyclerView`. Problem is that if there are many messages, then the `RecyclerView` goes crazy. It stops displaying right messages, it messes up with the order of messages and so on.

If I set `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` everything seems to work fine, but this is a poor solution in my humble opinion.

For the layout of a single item, I use custom `LinearLayout` view which may cause the problem here, but I'm not sure of it.

How to extort on the `RecyclerView` to preserve right order of added items?

Here's the adapter of my `RecyclerView`.

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    private List<String> messagesList = new LinkedList<>();

    public MessagesAdapter() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
            messagesList.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.message_list_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String message = messagesList.get(position);
        holder.mHeartBeatMessage.setText(message);
        // holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messagesList.size();
    }

    void addItem(String message) {
        this.messagesList.add(message);
    }

    static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.heartBeatMessage)
        protected HeartBeat mHeartBeatMessage;

        RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

I've found out that my Custom View generates the problem. I probably overworked it in a bad manner.

Here's my custom view which is held in adapter.

```
public class HeartBeat extends LinearLayout {
String mText = "";

public HeartBeat(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public HeartBeat(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public HeartBeat(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

/**
 * Initialize main variables.
 */
private void init(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.HeartBeat,
                0, 0);

        try {
            mText = a.getString(R.styleable.HeartBeat_text);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    ImageView heartBeat = new ImageView(context);
    heartBeat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_chat_heartbeat);
    heartBeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartbeat);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0);
    layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    heartBeat.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    addView(heartBeat);

    Drawable drawable = heartBeat.getDrawable();
    if (drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) {
        ((AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) drawable).registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(drawable);
                HeartBeat.this.removeAllViews();
                HeartBeat.this.addTextView(context);
            }
        });
        ((AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) drawable).start();
    } else if (drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ((AnimatedVectorDrawable) drawable).registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(drawable);
                    HeartBeat.this.removeAllViews();
                    HeartBeat.this.addTextView(context);
                }
            });
        }
        ((AnimatedVectorDrawable) drawable).start();
    }
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.mText = text;
}

private void addTextView(Context context) {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.chat_message);
    animation.reset();
    setAnimation(animation);

    TextView heartBeat = new TextView(context);
    heartBeat.setText(mText);
    heartBeat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_chat_message);
    heartBeat.setAnimation(animation);
    HeartBeat.this.addView(heartBeat);
}
}
```

Comment: `Source code:` please add relevant code into the question. We shouldn't have to go to any other sites to see the code. Add code of your adapter, and how you add items to it.

Comment: Please add the `onBindViewHolder` function from the adapter of your `RecyclerView` here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29980552/2308683

Answer (score 0):

As I have checked your code, you need to modify your `addItem` function in the `MessagesAdapter` class like this following.

```
void addItem(String message) {
    this.messagesList.add(message);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This should do the job of recycling your views.

Comment: Ideally you only notify an item is added, not the entire list

Comment: Yes, that is an improvement. Thanks @cricket_007.

Comment: I had notifyDataSetChanged(); and it doesn't help. It's because of my specific custom view. I probably overworked it in a bad manner.

Comment: So could you make it working now? Or the problem still persists?

Comment: The problem still persists. I've changed the custom view a little bit and now I use LinearLayout with two views in it and the RecyclerView maintains order.

Unfortunately, when I add more than 7 items to RecycleView, the first view (with animation) stops displaying. I've tried also to use onDraw() to draw custom animation but after adding more elements, onDraw() doesn't work properly, either. I must abandon my solution.

My goal was to create a list of messages, to be like in following design:
https://www.uplabs.com/posts/medical-bot-interactions